# ENC28J60 heating issues

Tags: pcb, ethernet, esp32, heat, enc28j60

Here, I add the schematic and PCB layout of ENC28J60 module. It's working properly, but it's getting too hot. It's around 103 Degree Fahrenheit. How can I minimize this heating issues?
[image]

[image]

Comment: which component in the module is getting  hot?

Comment: 103 deg F isn't hot. It's just a really nice warm temperature and nowhere near problematic for modern chips.

Comment: Ruman - Hi, Are those the schematic and PCB layout of your own design? Or are you using one of the pre-made ENC28J60 modules, so you have copied *their* schematic and PCB layout into the question? || If you have copied those images from elsewhere, please [edit] the question and add the name(s) & link(s) to the sources of those images, to comply with the [site rule on referencing](/help/referencing). TY

Comment: Just use an heatsink ...